# How do you change font color. - Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print in terminal with colors using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

Just curious

So I want to print 'Blah' in red how do i do this.

I only want to change the color of that statement.

Comment: oh so i have a program and that one single statement should be red

Comment: _If_ this is non-windows, world, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama and http://bmistudents.blogspot.com/2006/08/ansi-escape-codes-in-python.html

Comment: It is probably easier, at least in windows, to give the program a GUI with something like QT where you can control the color and every other aspect of the display relatively easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ANSI Colors, for your command line. But this isn't always supported by the computer.

With a litle bit of looking around on the web, I found this helpful link: http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/184/print-text-in-colors-with-a-simple-command-line/

Comment: That link doesn't explain how to do it from Python though.

Answer (score 1):

This will print red text in Terminal on OSX:

```
print '\033[91mWARNING\033[0m'
```